# Correct application of Leibniz Rule

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, leibniz-integral-rule

Consider the following integral

$$I = \int^b_af[x[t];c]dt$$

where $a,b$ and $c$ are scalers and $x[t]$ is a function of $t$. I want to know $\frac{\partial I}{\partial x}$.

If I apply Leibniz Rule, I get

$$\frac{\partial I}{\partial x} = \int^b_a\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dt$$

I feel this is an incorrect application of the rule, since $x$ is a function of $t$.

Alternatively, I can think of re-defining $f$ as $g = f[x+\epsilon;c]$, where for $\epsilon = 0$ we have the original function. Now if I apply Leibniz Rule by differentiating with respect to $\epsilon$ (and then evaluate the derivative at $\epsilon = 0$), I get,

$$\frac{\partial I}{\partial  \epsilon} = \int^b_a\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}|_{\epsilon=0}  dt$$

Questions:

1. Am I correct in saying that my first method is incorrect?
2. If the alternative method is correct, does it correctly capture $\frac{\partial I}{\partial x}$?

Edit:

It might help to explain what I was thinking of when I wrote the question:

Suppose $x$ represents monetary values at different points of time ($t$) and $f$ is a function of $x$. $I$ is adding $f$ from $t=a$ to $t=b$. I would like to calculate, how the sum ($I$) changes if the entire sequence $x$, say, goes up or down.

Comment: Regarding 1) note that you are taking the partial derivative.

Comment: @MathsWizzard I see. But $x$ is the only variable argument, so would it matter if I wrote  partial instead of total derivative?

Comment: $I$ is a number since bounds do not depend on $x$ so derivative is $0$.

Comment: @erik could you elaborate on what you mean by "if I wrote partial instead of total derivative" and where you consider writing this in your statement?

Comment: @MathsWizzard Sorry for not being clear. I meant if I wrote $\frac{d I}{d x}$ instead of $\frac{\partial I}{\partial x}$ would it make any difference? I think not, since $x$ is the only variable argument in $f$.

Comment: @erik I would still write it as partial derivative because remember that one could also take the derivative with respect to $t$ (by the fundamental theorem of calculus)

Comment: @MathsWizzard: $I$ is a function on the space of functions $x(t)$ (with domain $[a,b]$ and presumably some continuity/differentiability restrictions). This is called a *functional* in the calculus of variations literature. In no way is an integral $\int_a^b g(t)\,dt$ a function of $t$. At any rate, NO partial derivatives involved, but recognize that you're differentiating in an infinite-dimensional space.

Comment: Ted Shifrin has touched on your real problem: What exactly do you mean by $\frac {dI}{dx}$ when $x$ is not a real variable, but instead varies over a space of functions? There are various types of derivatives that can be defined from vector spaces, but which one are you trying to do? Your first method does not make sense. Your second method is a directional derivative in the direction of the constant function $1$, which is valid, but too restrictive to be truly useful. There are many other directions where $I$ changes differently.

Comment: @PaulSinclair what I tried to generalize was this:  If $x$ increased, how would $I$ be affected? For example, suppose $x$ represents monetary values at different points of time ($t$) and $f$ is a function of $x$. $I$ is adding $f$ from $t=a$ to $t=b$. What I want to know is how the sum ($I$) changes if the entire sequence $x$, say, goes up or down.

Comment: $x$ is a function, not a value. It can increase in many different ways. It can rise uniformly, as you've tried. But it can also rise faster in the middle than at the ends, or at $b$ faster than $a$, or even rise at $b$ while falling at $a$, or many, many other behaviors. If all you are interested in is what happens when $x$ rises by the same amount everywhere, your last integral will tell you. But if you want to understand how $I$ changes with $x$ in general, then you need $$\left.\dfrac d{ds}\right|_0 \int_a^bf(x(t) + sy(t); c)\,dt$$ for various functions $y$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thanks for that suggestion. I edited my question to add the clarification from the comments.